# Magento 2 admin login form redirect

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-login

Each time I attempt to login into admin panel, it redirects me to the same page with empty fields. This is happening just after I moved my server to another. I've checked all the internet for a solution, but I couldn't find one.

it sometime come up with different error that page load for long time and on the end it got me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS can any one help please ?

Comment: It could be due to the cookie settings. Check cookie path and cookie domain in core_config_data table.

Comment: Check the sessions folder in your server is writable?

Comment: @Shyam thanks for your replay i did try this i changed cookie path to / and cookie domain to my domain but nothing happened i tried to make it null but nothing solved.

Comment: @MohamedElMrabet i tried this i changed my sessions to files and correct all folders and files permissions but it doesn't solve my problem

it sometime come up with different error that page load for long time and on the end it got me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS 
can any one help please ?

Comment: With this error you have a boucle of redirection have you some custom change in Magento 2?

Comment: No i didn't it was working good on the old server all of this happen when we transferred to another host and till now front-end working with no issue just the back-end

Comment: Pls run commands: php bin/magento setup:upgrade, 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile & 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 1):

I keep encountering this problem on my test server when I migrate data or upgrade. You fix the cookie path but then need to clean cookies on the browser side (as already suggested in comments) but also sessions and content on the server side that might remember the wrong setting. Otherwise, things remain in a mismatch and redirect hell follows.

I'm not sure if all the steps are needed each have been needed in the past so I do all of them.

Here's what I just did on a bitnami test instance with just an IP today, on 2.2.2 .

- check/change cookie domain and cookie path to match local domain or ip
- clear browser cookie
- clear magento cache and static content
- check (and fix) ownership and writeability of the various folders in /var/ as they keep being left in an odd state by the magento command line actions (probably bitnami only)
- delete content of page_cache, cache etc. if not empty
- restart browser